# How to find out what Stack you are in in React Native using react-navigation whatever screen you are in in your react native project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-navigation

I am currently using React Native for the first time and I am trying to render a component in a particular screen depending on the parent stack I am in as the particular screen is reused across multiple stacks.

Right now I am doing this using the following:

```
props?.navigation.getState()?.routes?.[0]?.name
```

which is returning/having the desired effect, but I am unsure whether this is the optimal solution as I am a first-time React Native user. If multiple screens are opened, will the initial stack route always be found at

```
props?.navigation.getState()?.routes?.[0]?.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that for your need the getState will work just fine, but you may want to take a look at the [useNavigationState](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/) as it can re-render the component when that value changes

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
const { routes, index } = navigation.getState();
const currentRoute = routes[index].name;
```

- routes:- List of rendered routes.
- index:- Index of the currently focused route.